# Azure Search set disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn with .NET C# API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have a service that manages all of the indexes/indxers I use for Azure Cognitive Search, and within that I am attempting to set `disableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn` to true when creating/updating an indexer.

While I do see examples in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers) for an HTTP request to set that field, I'm not seeing any parameter anywhere (including the `Parameters` option under the `SearchIndexer` object) that can be set to update that value.

Does nadisableOrderByHighWaterMarkColumn` through the C# API? I have the latest Azure.Search.Documents package installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add it as a custom key under the [SearchIndexer.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.searchindexer.parameters?view=azure-dotnet#azure-search-documents-indexes-models-searchindexer-parameters).[IndexingParametersConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.indexingparameters.indexingparametersconfiguration?view=azure-dotnet#azure-search-documents-indexes-models-indexingparameters-indexingparametersconfiguration) property.

If for some reason that doesn't work as expected, then it is a bug with the .NET SDK that I would suggest you submit as an issue against t[he official Github repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/src/Indexes/Models).

Comment: Ah, a custom key, didn't think of doing that. Thank you.